# Rtsp streaming node

Tags: html, reactjs, rtsp

I need to display a live camera on a webpage, and this camera uses `rstp` protocol. I've just found out that browsers do not support `rtsp` protocol, so I need to create a `nodeJS` server to serve to the client(react) in order to make it work. I came across multiple information articles on the internet but nothing seems to work properly.
How can I accomplish this mission?

Comment: You can use FFmpeg to take your RTSP stream and output HLS segments, which can be played on your web page with HLS.js.  No need for Node.js.

Answer (score 2):

I too was researching on the same thing. What I found out was that we can convert our RTSP URL to HLS using FFMPEG and pass the HLS master file (.m3u8) to video tag in HTML to stream.

Let me know if it helps.

Example:

`<video id="video-player" controls preload="none"><source src="/output-directory/index.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL"></video>`